# Update actions from one sql table to another using Message Broker

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

i wanna use Wepshoere Message Broker to get the actions that any user perform on any table to be applied on another table

Example

1- User insert a record on Table x in TestDB

2- Message broker take this newly added record and add it to Table y in TestDB

could you support me with detailed information. and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you instead add an insert [trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) to Table x, this is a normal function for database triggers.

It would help if you update your question with the DBMS and OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this using a dbInput node to fire a message when the table is updated and then use normal ESQL or the mapping node to do the insert in the target table.

The key thing is going to be configuring your db input node correctly, you can get more info on how to do that here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc34041_.htm